# Page file on a separate partition in Windows

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, swap, pagefile

I have recently rebuilt my computer (Windows 7 Pro 32bit), and am in the process of paritioning my hard drive. My question is, is it beneficial to make a separate partition for the page file, rather than have it on the same drive as the Operating System (C:)?

I am thinking of making a 5GB partition called Swap (S:) that will contain the a 4458MB (As advised by Windows) page file, whereas the C drive will contain none. Is it bad for the only page file to be on this partition and to have none on the C drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in the past, where I had a very locked-down C: drive.  It works fine, but there are two things to bear in mind:

1. You won't gain much speed, as it's still on the same physical device.
2. If you put the C: partition first on the drive, then your swap will be on the outer edge of the disk, which is traditionally slower.

Comment: Right, so there's no particularly large downsides to it?

Comment: Yep, there aren't any really good reasons for not doing it, other than the management overhead for minimal gain.

Comment: Actually, putting the pagefile in a separate partition from your OS will slow things down, as the access arm will have to move farther.